# Unknown column 'name' in 'field list

Tags: c#, mysql

```
        MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(mysqladdress);
        cnn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Registered!");

        MySqlCommand cmdinsert;

        try
        {
            cmdinsert = cnn.CreateCommand();
            cmdinsert.CommandText = "Insert into student(Name,Age,School,StudentID,Username,Password) values (@Name,@Age,@School,@StudentID,@Username,@Password)";
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox1.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox2.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@School", textBox3.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", textBox5.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox6.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox7.Text.ToString());
            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                cnn.Close();
                datagridviewfunction();
            }
        }
```

**there's always error saying: "Unknown column 'StudentID' in 'field list'"
the problem is in "throw"
what to do? please help me so i can move to the next form **

Comment: Check your database, that error means there's no field named StudentID on the table.

Comment: Also, as a side note, a catch with a throw will do nothing, if you want to throw the error just remove the catch{} clausule.

Comment: Just check Student ID carefully. there possibly a problem in there

Comment: i get it! thanks :)